# Parameterizing event handlers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput library to create tags in my application. Very weird things are happening when I try to bind renderTag property to a custom function. I think I am missing a point related to JavaScript, not react.

Even though the typeof tagType returns 'string' on component, when I try to render that, it renders [object Object] | hello. Why does it render Object?

```
  defaultRenderTag = (customProps, props) => {
let { tag, key, disabled, onRemove, classNameRemove, getTagDisplayValue, ...other } = props
let { tagType } = customProps;

// This returns 'string'
console.log(typeof tagType)

return (
  <span key={key} {...other}>
    {/* The type of the tag: */}
    {
      tagType ? (
        // This returns "[object Object] | work"

        <span className="react-tagsinput-tagtype"> {tagType} </span> + ' | '
      ) : null
    }
    {getTagDisplayValue(tag)}
    {!disabled &&
      <a className={classNameRemove} onClick={(e) => onRemove(key)} />
    }
  </span>
)
```

}

This is the main component that I use the function above:

```
 <TagsInput
      ...
      renderTag={this.defaultRenderTag.bind(this, { tagType: 'personal' })}
      ...
 />
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add a string to JSX there.

Comment: I don't get it. I am trying to render tagType 'personal' in JSX.

Comment: Oh my god @Colin! I've just seen what you mean. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using string concatenation in JSX `<span className="react-tagsinput-tagtype"> {tagType} </span> + ' | '`, the `<span>...</span>` prints as [Object object]. You can try the below alternative:

```js
return (
  <span key={key} {...other}>
    {
      tagType && <span className="react-tagsinput-tagtype"> {`${tagType} | `} </span>
    }
    {getTagDisplayValue(tag)}
    {!disabled &&
      <a className={classNameRemove} onClick={(e) => onRemove(key)} />
    }
  </span>
)
```

Comment: Thanks @colin and swati for the answer!